basins of attraction for dynamical system
How can I plot basins of attraction of the following system:
diff(Phi(xi),xi)=T,
diff(T(xi),xi)=-w[1]Phi^3-w[2]Phi+fsin[yxi]
when w[1]=1.5, w[2]=0.1, f=8.1, and y=0.22 with the initial condition (Phi (0),T(0))=(0.29,0.13)
I used the Runge Kutta method to study the multistability behavior of the dynamical system and I want to plot the basins of attraction graphs. How can I do this with maple or mathematica?

this may be better directed to https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/
